# Will EF recognize changes to an entity altered outside of the Service's scope?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Given a `Service` and a `Helper`class, if an object is created in the `Service`, passed back to the calling `Helper` class, then altered, if we call `SaveChanges()`, will Entity Framework recognize and apply the changes?

**Helper Class**

```
public MyHelper {
    private readonly Service _Service;
    private DoStuff(){
        PersonEntity myPerson = this._Service.CreateNewPerson();
        myPerson.Name = "Hank";
        this._Service.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

**Service Class**

```
public Service {
    private readonly DbContext _Context;
    public Service(DbContext context){ //instantiated via Dependency Injection
        this._Context = context;
    }

    public Task<PersonEntity> CreateNewPerson() {
        PersonEntity toReturn = new PersonEntity() {
            Name = "Jeff"
        };

        this._Context.People.Add(toReturn);
        return toReturn;
    }

    public Task SaveChangesAsync(){
        // Will the PersonEntity.Name be updated to 'Hank'?
        await this._Context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Only have notepad at the moment :(

Comment: EF will mirror all entities in the context when calling savechanges. so, when your object is in the context and its entitystate is added or modified, changes will be written to db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should detect the changes.

The way it works behind the scenes is that when you load an entity from a context, the context (actually a `DbChangeTracker` attached to the context, to be specific) will take a snapshot of the entity.  When you call `SaveChanges` the context will scan the entity graph and compare it to the snapshot looking for things that changed.  Based on that, no matter where or how the change happened, the context should see the changes.

This is why it can be important to use `.AsNoTracking` when you do not plan on updating the entities you retrieve.  It prevents the context from taking the snapshot, improving memory usage and performance.

Comment: As a reference, syntax for AsNoTracking is as such: `DbContextInstance.Set<PersonEntity>().AsNoTracking();`

Comment: @LeviFuller That will actually turn off change tracking for an entire entity type (which I wasn't even aware you could do).  If you want to disable it for a single query it looks like `Context.SomeEntity.AsNoTracking`. Or `Context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled  = false;` to turn it off for the entire context.

Comment: Good to note; So the full syntax for a single object without tracking is: `SomeEntity myEntity = Context.SomeEntity.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(entity => entity.Id == someId);`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should automatically detect the changes.

Comment: Just what I wanted to hear! Thanks, mate. Care to elaborate on how it works?

Comment: You have to learn about the Change Trackers: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/change-tracking-in-entity-framework.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: If the context is not disposed of before calling the `SaveChanges()`, after making the changes in the entity object, then it should directly detect the changes. However, if the context is not same, then you might need to attach the object (to put it in the context), before calling `SaveChanges()`.